# How much do recruiting companies pay for the freelance selection process

Tags: contracts, pay-rate, price

A recruiting company offered me to work as a freelance paid for a success fee.

When the company hires the candidate, the position is closed positively and my partner invoices between 10 and 20% of the annual salary.
Everyone who helped find the customer, identify the candidate, or participated in the screening and interview process gets a share.

**How much is the screening and interview service worth** and what are the *risks or benefits*, compared to other activities?

PS *I just arrived here on "StackExchange" and I hope to be "in topic". Thank you for any suggestion*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, these placement firms don't do anything close to justifying their residual fee and add no value in the process besides connecting you to a gig opportunity.  Unfortunately, unless you have a process to find work, you are stuck using this process. If you know of multiple placement firms and you have a skill set that is high in demand, you may want to try to negotiate up front to either lower the % or ask for a set duration that they take this fee (vs until the contract ends).

Answer (score 1):

The fees that recruiting companies charge for freelance selection processes can vary widely based on several factors, including the level of expertise required, the complexity of the role, the industry, and the region. Typically, recruiting firms charge a percentage of the freelancer's or contractor's first-year annual income, but they may also use other fee structures.

In general, recruitment agencies often charge fees ranging from 15% to 25% of the freelancer's annual income for their services. However, these percentages can be higher or lower depending on the factors mentioned above. Some agencies may also charge additional fees for services such as advertising the job, conducting interviews, or providing candidate assessments.

It's essential to discuss and negotiate the fees with the recruiting company before engaging their services to ensure clarity on costs and to align expectations. Keep in mind that the freelance job market is dynamic, and fee structures may vary based on the specific requirements of the hiring organization and the freelancer being sought.